# Link to archive post type on the specific post

Tags: wordpress, anchor

I have this code in the loop on my post :

```
<div class="retour"><a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'projets' ); ?>">Projets</a></div>
```

When it goes to the post_type_archive page, I'd like my browser to go directly on the specific post.

Can I add an anchor tag to my function ?

How can I manage that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Just add an anchor tag to the end like this:

```
<div class="retour"><a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'projets' ); ?>#youranchor">Projets</a></div>
```